# SQL LEFT JOIN with CASE expressions

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to build an SQL SELECT query which grabs information from two different tables and groups them by an order ID. Currently, I've gotten down to this query:

```
SELECT T1.order_item_id, T2.order_item_id, T2.order_id, T3.post_id, 
       CASE WHEN T1.meta_key = 'Name' and T2.order_item_id = T1.order_item_id 
            THEN T3.meta_value 
            END as name, 
       CASE WHEN T3.meta_key = '_billing_address' and T2.order_id = T3.post_id 
            THEN T3.meta_value 
            END as billing_address, 
       CASE WHEN T3.meta_key = '_billing_email' and T2.order_id = T3.post_id 
            THEN T3.meta_value 
            END as billing_email 
FROM wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta T1 
LEFT JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_items T2 
       ON T1.order_item_id = T2.order_item_id 
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta T3 
       ON T2.order_id = T3.post_id
```

and here are the tables I'm grabbing from:

T1:

```
 +---------------------------------------+
 | order_item_id | meta_key | meta_value|
 +---------------------------------------+
 | 1             | Name     | John Doe   |                      
 +---------------------------------------+
```

T2

```
 +---------------------------------------+
 | order_item_id  |  order_id            |
 +---------------------------------------+
 | 1              |  101                 |
 +---------------------------------------+
```

T3

```
 +-------------------------------------------------+
 | post_id   | meta_key         | meta_value       |
 +-------------------------------------------------+
 | 101       | _billing_address | 123 Fake St.     |
 | 101       | _billing_email   | jondoe@gmail.com |
 +-------------------------------------------------+
```

I want to be able to create a table that looks like this:

```
 +-------------------------------------------------------+
 | order_id | name     | address      | email            |
 +-------------------------------------------------------+
 | 101      | John Doe | 123 Fake St. | jondoe@gmail.com |                                 
 +-------------------------------------------------------+
```

But the table that the aforementioned SQL query produces has numerous null values for the billing address, name and email, and just doesn't seem to be grabbing the data from the cells.

I feel like the CASE expression might be the issue, but I'm not entirely sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the conditional part down, now add some aggregation using `max()` to solve this with conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT 
    T1.order_item_id
  , T2.order_item_id
  , T2.order_id
  , T3.post_id
  , max(CASE WHEN T1.meta_key = 'Name' and T2.order_item_id = T1.order_item_id 
            THEN T3.meta_value 
            END) as name
  , max(CASE WHEN T3.meta_key = '_billing_address' and T2.order_id = T3.post_id 
            THEN T3.meta_value 
            END) as billing_address
  , max(CASE WHEN T3.meta_key = '_billing_email' and T2.order_id = T3.post_id 
            THEN T3.meta_value 
            END) as billing_email 
FROM wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta T1 
  LEFT JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_items T2 
    ON T1.order_item_id = T2.order_item_id 
  LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta T3 
    ON T2.order_id = T3.post_id
group by 
    T1.order_item_id
  , T2.order_item_id
  , T2.order_id
  , T3.post_id
```

---

It also looks like you can simplify your case statements like so:

```
SELECT 
    T1.order_item_id
  , T2.order_item_id
  , T2.order_id
  , T3.post_id
  , T1.meta_value as name
  , max(CASE WHEN T3.meta_key = '_billing_address' THEN T3.meta_value END) as billing_address
  , max(CASE WHEN T3.meta_key = '_billing_email' THEN T3.meta_value END) as billing_email 
FROM wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta T1 
  LEFT JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_items T2 
    ON T1.order_item_id = T2.order_item_id 
  LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta T3 
    ON T2.order_id = T3.post_id
where t1.meta_key = 'Name'
group by 
    T1.order_item_id
  , T2.order_item_id
  , T2.order_id
  , T3.post_id
```

Comment: I was thinking the same thing about them being able to simplify their case conditions, but that may not be quite right either; since they are using left joins, conditions like `T2.order_item_id = T1.order_item_id` may only be simplified to `T2.order_item_id IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: @AaronDietz I don't believe that they are, and I added a simplified version without that part. Ask OP. It's hard to know without making assumptions about the rest of the data. It may just be leftover code from other attempts at getting their desired result.

Comment: Uueerdo, I'll try testing that. The reason that condition exists is because I was trying to link orders between three different tables while retaining the specific name of the product that was being ordered.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you left join twice on a selection of the postmeta table, the query is a lot easier:

```
SELECT T1.order_item_id, T2.order_item_id, T2.order_id, T3.post_id, 
T1.meta_key as name, 
T3A.meta_key as address, 
T3E.meta_key as email, 

FROM wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta T1 
LEFT JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_items T2 
       ON T1.order_item_id = T2.order_item_id 
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta T3A 
       ON T2.order_id = T3A.post_id AND T3A.meta_key = '_billing_address'
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta T3E
       ON T2.order_id = T3E.post_id AND T3E.meta_key = '_billing_email'
```

NB: this query isn't tested, but maybe you could provide an example database